# How do I handle interaction between the DOM and the Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-controller

The more I read (and try to test) Angular apps, I'm seeing that it is bad practice for a controller to refer to the DOM.  (e.g. [this blog post](http://blog.nebithi.com/angularjs-dos-and-donts/)).

I must be missing something big, because if the controller can't access the DOM (e.g. by "regular" javascript calls like `document.getElementsByClassName`), then I don't understand how to do a lot of things I'd consider very basic.

Here's a contrived, simple example that has some of the same problems that my app does:

- I have a directive that is simply a red box (a div with some styles applied), and uses ng-transclude.  So I'd use it in my html file like `<red-box>Text that goes in the red box</red-box>`
- A button, when clicked, changes the color of all red boxes to blue.  I would have something like this in my html file:  `<intput type="button" value="Make Them Blue" ng-click="makeThemBlue"/>`
- In the controller's `makeThemBlue` function, I'd (for example) find all of the divs by class name, and change the class to something else which makes them blue

Now consider that my real app is much more complicated - many "boxes" consisting of nested directives, that can be dragged around, and have their positions saved.  The controller reads all of the saved settings, and lays everything out according to how the user saved it.

How would I do something like either of the above examples without having the controller access the DOM?

Answer (score 2):

Here are my key rules:

1. `Directives` - For solid components and for DOM manipulation.
2. `Services` - For business logic and saving state.  Directives, Controllers, Services etc. should use them.
3. `Controllers` - A views helper. No business logic should be executed inside. For complicated issues use a service.

In your case a box should be a `directive`.
You directive will use an observable `service` and register for the click event.
When the click event occurs, the observer will notify all the registered `directive` instances that it was clicked, and you should apply to that in your `directive`.

Comment: Hmmm...ok. Let's take the even simpler case where there is one red box, and when the user clicks it, it turns blue.  In this case I don't think we'd need the service, right?  So in the directive itself there will be code to get the DOM element?  Or is there some way I can say something like `this.setStyle('background-color', 'blue') right in the directive?

Comment: In this case it is simpler.
Your templatehtml will be something like this: `<div ng-class="boxClass" ng-click="toggleBoxClass()"></div>`
`ng-class` will point to a string on your scope and `ng-click` will change it from
redClass to blueClass.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Directives for this purpose.

See the documentation for Directive

[Angular Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

It gives you a built in jquery like functionality to Access Dom

the link function in Directive is amazing to Manipulate Dom with the same syntax(almost) as jquery.

Further You can Maintain Chunks of Functionality By Making Services , So you can separate each login plus you have Access to Dom and can manipulate them easily

Injecting services to controller function of directive will give you to maintain code reuseability.

Answer (score 0):

By having the DOM access the controller (or natively from within the directive). This is what the declarative paradigm is all about.

If your box needs to change it's color, have it read that value, or a class, or whatever you need, from a value in the controller, or in the directive itself.

In a very basic sense:

`<my-directive color="getColor()"></my-directive>`